# How can I retrieve text data from Whatsapp messages in Python Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, whatsapp, data-extraction

I am desperately looking for solutions.
So far I have covered the following steps.
1- Selenium webdriver installed
2- login on whatsapp using QR code

I am trying hard to get data from one of my contact through class_names, but still not successful. My code is as below:

'''

```
PATH = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
sleep(13)
chats=[]
print("Chrome has been automated",eta(time()))
elem = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_3j8Pd')
elem[1].click()
sleep(10)
print("Web Whatsapp Authetication success",eta(time()))
while(True):
    scroll()
    contacts = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('._3NWy8 span')
    newcon=set([j.text for j in contacts])
    if len(newcon|mycon)==len(mycon):
        break
    else:
        mycon=newcon|mycon
contact=sorted(list(mycon),key=str.casefold)
rotate=dict()
print(len(contact),"contacts has been retrieved",eta(time()))
```

'''

Comment: What is error you are getting? And are you trying extract all the messages or `from` messages.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please explain the error you are receiving at your end or at what portion of code you are facing an issue. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "elem[1].click() is out of bounds"                                                                              I am beginner, I checked the below mentioned code (copied) to extract all contacts so I can get the messages of desired contact. But I am not able to extract contacts names, so cannot find message.                                                                                    elem = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_3j8Pd')
elem[1].click()
sleep(10)
print("Web Whatsapp Authetication success",eta(time())).

Comment: "elem[1].click() is out of bounds"                        whenever I try to extract list of contacts, list is empty

Answer (score 0):

I tried to extract all the messages. And it worked with below code.

```
con = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("class_name")
con[-1].click() #Selecting the 1st message.
time.sleep(5) #for manually scrolling upwards.
msgs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='class_name']/span/span")
for msg in msgs:
    print(msg.text)
```

For `con` below was `div` tag:

```
<div class="_**_**" style="z-index: 0; transition: none 0s ease 0s; height: 72px; transform: translateY(0px);">
```

For `msgs` below was the `div` tag:

```
<div class="_*****">
<span dir="ltr" class="_***** selectable-text copyable-text">
<span> msg </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Please respond how to specify "class_name"...? I am a beginner, I have no idea about particular class names and categories.

Comment: @M.RehanRiaz The reason why I mention `class_name`  instead of actual class name was because it might differ based on the person's account.

Comment: @M.RehanRiaz - Have updated the answer with HTML. I hope that helps.

Comment: @M.RehanRiaz - And also I observed that the list `con` is in reverse order. That is `con[0]` element points to last contact. So I used `con[-1]` to get first contact's messages.